# An inequality involving the Mahler measure and the discriminant of a polynomial

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $F(x,y) = a_0 \prod_{i=1}^d(x-\alpha_iy)$ be a binary form of degree $d \geq 2$ and nonzero discriminant $D(F)$. Define the Mahler measure $M(F)$ of $F$ by

$$M(F) = \left|a_0\right| \prod\limits_{i=1}^d\max\{1,|\alpha_i|\}.$$

Further, for any matrix

$$A = \left(\begin{matrix}a & b\\c & d\end{matrix}\right),$$

whose entries are integers, define

$$F_A(x,y) = F(ax + by, cx + dy)$$

and let

$$
M_0(F) = \inf\limits_{A \in \operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb Z)}\{M(F_A)\}.
$$

In [1], K. Mahler showed that

$$|D(F)| \leq d^dM_0(F)^{2d-2};$$

in other words, he obtained an upper bound on $|D(F)|$ of the form $c_0(d)M_0(F)^{c_1(d)}$, where $c_0$ and $c_1$ are positive quantities which depend only on $d$. I wonder if a similar lower bound exists.

[1] K. Mahler, *An inequality for the discriminant of a polynomial*, Michigan Math. J. 11, pp. 257 - 262, 1964.

Comment: Was Mahler's bound in terms of $M_0(F)$, or in terms of $M(F)$?

Comment: It was in terms of $M(F)$. But that doesn't matter, since $|D(F)|=|D(F_A)|$ for any $A \in \operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb Z)$. As a result, $|D(F)| = |D(F_A)| \leq d^d M(F_A)^{2d-2}$ for any $A \in \operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb Z)$, and therefore $|D(F)| \leq d^dM_0(F)^{2d-2}$.